# Django - Condition in clean_fieldname generates ValidationError when it shouldn't

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a very basic clean_fieldname function:

```
def clean_fieldname(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['fieldname']
        if data is not None:
            if data < 0.5 or data > 1:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Please input value between 0.5 and 1")
        return data
```

fieldname is defined as in:

```
fieldname   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2, default=1)
```

If the field is 0.5 it will raise a form.ValidationError. How can that happen?

I tried in Python and of course 0.5 is not < 0.5. So it shouldn't pass the condition, but in Django 1.6 it does. Why is that?

**Update:**
The clean method is overridden with something similar as:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
    fieldname    = cleaned_data.get("fieldname")
    telephone    = cleaned_data.get("telephone")
    myname       = cleaned_data.get("myname")

    if (telephone or myname is not None) and (fieldname is not None):
        raise forms.ValidationError("You forgot to write fieldname.")

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: How is the field defined? Is it a charfield, floatfield, decimal, what?

Comment: Updated with fieldname definition

Comment: Can you debug it and see what are the type and value of data?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida I just did `print repr(data)` and it returns `Decimal('0.5')` which is what I expected. If I just do `print data` it will return `0.5`. The `clean` method is overriden. See my updated answer. Thanks!

Comment: What is your version of Python? By the way, did you try the comparison with `Decimal` in the Python shell?

Comment: @PauloALmeida I have Python 2.7. I Python shell it's working as expected. Only solution I have right now is to change 0.5 to 0.49. But I don't see that as the best solution. Thanks!